# Autolayout CollectionView

Tags: iphone, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to use autolayout for a CollectionVIew, but when I run it in iPhone plus, a space is created between the cells.

iPhone 8 Plus
[image]

iPhone 8 
[image]

Comment: If your cell width is not half of the screen, that will happen. Show your code for the cell.

Comment: you should calculate cell size according to view.bounds.width

Comment: @RakeshaShastri the code for the cell is pretty simple, I do nothing there just set the info.

Comment: Show what you do there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already set the cell size from collection view's delegate method. One thing you need to do is to call `invalidateLayout()` whenever the collection view's frame changes, so it will re-render the cells.

IE:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting in ViewDidLoad the size of the cell (I just set the width, but you could set the height too)

```
let layout = YourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout?.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width / 2 , height: 114)
```